# Dragging error from Database explorer to crystal reprort data tab or pane

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Could not Add Object. Unexpected ValueType: ValueType=[255]

I appreciate any idea?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail. What version of the software are you using? Which operating system?

Comment: @ alfredocambera operating system: ubuntu14.04 eclipse: eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk crystal report: cr4e_2.0.18 database: postgresql 8.1  plug-in/postgresql jdbc driver: postgresql 8.1-404.jdbc3.jar